# Swiping to make ImageButton disappear / appear

Tags: android, menu, swipe, imagebutton, gesture

I've a menu in Android app with several **ImageButton** (all grouped in a **RelativeLayout**) and I would like to make it disappear when **swiping** with finger towards the outside of the screen.
Swiping with finger towards the inside of the screen, instead, the menu should re-appear.
Any suggestion to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing a gesture detection as given here [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) and in that code instead of toast write your code.

Comment: missed it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection